# Hilt provide dependency after making a network call

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I need to provide a graph client for Storefront API but I can only build the client after making a network call.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun getGraphClient(context: Context, client: Client): GraphClient {
    return GraphClient.build(
        context = context,
        shopDomain = client.shopifyDomain,
        accessToken = client.storefrontAccessToken
    )
}
```

How can I after making a network call to get the client pass it to hilt to return the graph client?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manual dependency injection like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    var graphClient: GraphClient? = null

    fun provideGraphClient(context: Context, client: Client) {
        graphClient = GraphClient.build(
            context = context,
            shopDomain = client.shopifyDomain,
            accessToken = client.storefrontAccessToken
        )
    }
}
```

And then after the API call

```
AppModule.provideGraphClient(context, client)
```

And inject into any repository like this:

```
class SomeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val applicationContext: Context,
    private val graphClient: GraphClient? = AppModule.graphClient
) : SomeRepository {

....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not Hilt approach at all. You could do it without @Module interface. You should provide the GraphClient like you did before and inject like following:

```
   class SomeRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val applicationContext: Context,
    private lateinit val graphClient: GraphClient
  ) : SomeRepository {

  ....

  }
```

if you are not familiar with kotlin "lateinit" then you will find out the reference does not instantiate until it's used somewhere for the first time.
I added lateinit keyword and modified a little of your mentioned code snippet.
Please let me know if this works, If you don't find it helpful - just let me know in comments. I will definitely sole your hilt issues.

As your post is much older and you may already know a better approach. But I just don't want anyone confused others that your solution is not actual Hilt way. So I thought i should guide you to the solution an expert do in production codes.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. However I have solved this in another way using multibinding and initialising graph client in Application class. Ref: https://adambennett.dev/2021/03/intoset-dagger-multibindings-and-architecture/